# Show that $x-1$ is a factor of $P(x)$ where $P(x^5)+xQ(x^5)+x^2R(x^5)=\big(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\big)S(x)$

Tags: polynomials, proof-writing, contest-math

For the problem below, my first step was to rewrite the right side as

$$\big(x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1\big)S(x)=\frac{x^5-1}{x-1}S(x)$$

From there I can isolate $P(x^5)$ which gives me

$$P(x^5)=\dfrac{S(x)(x^5-1)-x(x-1)\big(Q(x^5)-xR(x^5)\big)}{x-1}$$

I'm not sure how to move forward.  To get $P(x)$ should I rewrite all the $x^5$ as $x$ and take the $5^{th}$ root of each $x$?  The questions prior used the idea of roots of unity so perhaps I can use that somehow.

Thanks

---

[image]

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** You know that if $P(1)=0$, then $x-1$ is a factor of $P$. Try plugging in special values of $x$ into the given functional equation. Try certain algebraic numbers with nice properties, such as, for example, the roots of unity.

Comment: In the other answer to this same question, they say that "Plugging in $\omega, \omega^2, \cdots,\omega^4$ in the equations successively we get that 
 $P(1)+xQ(1)+x^2 R(1) = 0$ for four distinct complex numbers. Hence it must be identically 0."  They then conclude that $P(1),Q(1),R(1)=0$.  Why is it that $4$ different values of $x$ all giving $0$ implies that the $3$ polynomials equal $0$ at $1$?  Thanks for the response

Comment: Because quadratic function can not cut a horizontal line more than twice.

Comment: @greedoid So we could've made the same conclusion by just showing that $3$ different values of $x$ make the right side equal to $0$